# WCF wsdualhttpbinding strange behaviour at client side that has no clear (Exception details)

Tags: wcf, iis-6, wsdualhttpbinding

to make long story as short as possible, I made a duplex WCF service, using wsdualhttpbinding, tested it on my local machine using Visual Stuido and using IIS7, thigs are working fine (i had to use windows authentication on IIS7 to make it work thu). Any way, I published the duplex service on my company network (LAN network, windows domain, IIS 6) which i used to for many WCF services (basic and ws http bindings and worked fine) and the problem is I can not get the service to work, I tried all possible configurations to the app.config and to the web.config files, still i can not make it work.. The problem is when the client start calling the duplex service It hangs and no error message or whatsoever, and after few minutes it gives me a timeout error.. there is no error at server side ( i have checked the even viewer). There is not error about port 80 or access privileges. Is there anything i am missing? anything i should take care of and i forgot? i have been awake for 20 hours trying to find a solution because i have a time line to follow or my boss will Dispose() Me.. 
i have tried the following:
1- I set the IsOneWay = true..
2- I run the program as admin.
3- I i set the base address to another port.. same result..
4- I used windows auth, none... same result..
5- i have tried another machine to test the client.. same result.. it hangs with no reponse.
6- I also tried running the client on windows vista, 7 and xp... same result..
7- I have played with all kind of configurations in config files and i made sure its the same on both files (app.config and web.config)..
8- I have added a static constructor in the service side to see if the service was ever reached by the client, i added few lines to add a value in the db.. and nothing was written to db.. so it was never reached..
9- Yes, when i access the service SVC page i see the page and it worked fine.. I could access the metadata as well..
10- restarting the server, restarting IIS server, Recycling AppPool...etc..

I tried all of that and many other solutions and tricks.. same result when the app is on IIS.. the strange thing is, there is no error at server side.. and i only get TimeOut error (if i get it).. While If i tried the service on the IIS installed locally it works fine.. change the config file to point to the company IIS server,,, no luck!

**Is there anything i am missing??? could be something simple but i just missed it..**

Comment: Have you run fiddler on the web server machine to see if the request is ever being received by the web server?

Comment: Suggestions: 1) get some sleep. 2) Install the service on a local IIS server similar to how it's running in production.

Comment: @competent_tech I tried fiddler just now.. It sends a request (SOAP envelope).. so i guess the request is sent.. something is wrong from the server side.. but why there is not reply from the server.. nothing in the event viewer... something is strange here.. suggestions?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I will try installing IIS6 on a pc and test there.. and i will sleep for sure now.. hoping for answers by the time i wake up

Comment: Only two things I can think of: 1) You have a blocking condition in your code on the server (infinite loop, deadlock, waiting on a resource that isn't available), 2) The response is sent back on a different port that is blocked by a firewall or routed to a different address for some reason (fiddler should be able to catch the outbound response, if any).

Comment: I guess i can rule out option no. 1... i made an empty method that returns nothing.. and still no response.. regarding fiddler, do you suggest running it on the server as well?

Comment: just to let you know if someone has the same problem, i cancelled the idea of using the duplex WCF for now and i used the idea presented in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116669/ways-to-make-two-way-communications-for-notification-using-net